# I get this error: Property or method "auto_password" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I am creating a Vue snippet inside a Laravel view, which would disable a text field when a user checks a checkbox. However I am getting this error in console:

> *[Vue warn]: Property or method "auto_password" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.*

This are the views:

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.manage')

@section('content')
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="columns m-t-10">
        <div class="column">
            <h1 class="title">Create New User</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr class="m-t-0">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="POST">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
                        <p class="control">
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name">
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="email" class="label">Email:</label>
                        <p class="control is-expanded">
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email">
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                        <p class="control">
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password" v-if="!auto_password">

                            <b-checkbox name="auto_generate"  class="m-t-15" v-model="auto_password">Auto Generate Password</b-checkbox>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="button is-success">Create User</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>{{-- end of .flex-container --}}
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            auto_password: true

        },

    })
</script>
@endsection
```

**layouts.manage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>AdBlog - Management</title>

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
@include('_includes.nav.main')
@include('_includes.nav.manage')

<div class ="management-area" id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: v-model will not work with component `b-checkbox`, share complete code,  or demo

Comment: That is the complete relevant code. I am using Buefy (https://buefy.github.io) for the UI hence the `b-checkbox` element

Answer (score 0):

Remove this piece from your `app.js` in assets:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {}
})
```